# Escape string value for plist with php

Tags: php, iphone, plist

How can I escape a string containing random characters with php for a plist file? `htmlentities()` seems doesn't seem to be strict enough. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <string><?php echo htmlentities("@!£$%^&*)}{:|<>/");?></string>
</plist>
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show what doesn't work?

Comment: XML parser error:
 Encountered unknown ampersand-escape sequence at line 3
Old-style plist parser error:
 Malformed data byte group at line 1; invalid hex

Comment: This makes sense because `htmlentities` is for .. well... HTML.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**CDATA**](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) should be the correct way:

```
 <plist version="1.0">
  <string><![CDATA[<?php echo "@!£$%^&*)}{:|<>/"; ?>]]></string>
 </plist>
```

The only thing in the content you would have to escape is the actual `<![CDATA[` opener itself.

If that doesn't work for some reasons, [**rawurlencode()**](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) turns all non-alphanumeric characters into RFC 1738 codes, which your target may be able to digest more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Don't all plist start with a `<dict>`?

`htmlentities` should work. You only need to escape `&` to `&amp;`, `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;`.